# Main Class Jar Exception

Tags: java, class

I'm new to the java language. I am trying to understand what exactly the class loader of JVM does.

I wrote a simple java program and copied the `.java` file in the
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333\jre\lib\ext`
and tried to compile it. After that when the `javac` command created a `.class` file, I converted it into a `jar` file and deleted the `.class` file.

So when I tried to run the jar with java filename the output of `cmd` displayed like this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Testing_prog
```

`Testing_prog` is my converted jar file.

Please  Help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: Seems like your jar's manifest is missing the main class value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.